# Shift several graphs under each other

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to shift several graphs under each other. I read in the data as an array with 4 columns in the data:

```
# load data for variable intensities
data_with_minimum = []
for i in [6, 12, 25, 50, 100]:
   data_with_minimum.append(np.loadtxt('data{0}.dat'.format(i)))
```

then I search for a characteristic point, in this case a minimum in the first 5000 rows(I know that there always is a minimum) and saving the indixes.

```
# open arrays for minimum value and index
m = []
mi = []
for k in range(5):
    m.append(0)
    mi.append(0)
    # search minimum in first 5000 data points
    for i in range(5000):
        if m[k] > data_with_minimum[k][i,1]:
            m[k] = data_with_minimum[k][i,1]
            mi[k] = i
```

Lastly, I want to shift every minimum from the first column under each other:

```
# shift x-axis
for i in range(30000 - m_max):
    for k in range(5):
        data_with_minimum[k][i,1] = data_with_minimum[k][i+(mi[k]-min(mi)),1]
```

Unfortunately this is not working, because the values are redefining itself. Because I'm quite new to Python I got stuck. So any suggestions would be helpful. Or is there maybe in general an easier way to solve this problem? This seems to me inconvenient.. Thank you!

edit:

1) Unfortunately I can't post images because I've not enough reputation points. So I need to post this link [shift graphs](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3519/pgujen49_png.htm). Sorry for that. My goal is that the minima of all graphs are at the same point. This graph was plotted with the command:

```
plt.figure(0)
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(data_with_minimum[i][:,0], data_with_minimum[i][:,1])
```

Minimum data example:

```
x   y(file1) y(file2) y(file3)
1   5        8        3
2   3        6        1
3   1        5        5
4   2        3        8
5   5        1        10
6   8        3        13
7   10       4        15
8   14       7        18
9   16       10       20
...
```

this should become

```
x   y(file1) y(file2) y(file3)
1   3        3        3
2   1        1        1
3   2        3        5
4   5        4        8
5   8        7       10
6   10      10       13
7   14       -       15
8   16       -       18
9   -        -       20
...
```

with 1 the minimum. But there is to mention that it could be possible that there's an additional minimum after the 5000 first data points. 
And the Beginning of the real data of one file:

```
0.000000    -1.057758   
0.000200    -1.051918   
0.000400    -1.063922   
0.000600    -1.065220
0.000800    -1.069438   
0.001000    -1.065220           
0.001400    -1.065545   
0.001600    -1.077549   
0.001800    -1.072682   
0.002000    -1.082416   
0.002200    -1.078847   
0.002400    -1.090203   
0.002600    -1.087283   
0.002800    -1.095069   
0.003000    -1.090527   
0.003200    -1.098314   
0.003400    -1.100261   
0.003600    -1.108372   
0.003800    -1.103505   
0.004000    -1.111292   
0.004200    -1.107074   
0.004400    -1.113887   
0.004600    -1.112590   
0.004800    -1.127514   
0.005000    -1.115510   
0.005200    -1.127514   
...
```

2) changed columns to rows in the passage "in this case a minimum in the first 5000 columns"

Comment: I don't really understand what this means. Could you show an example, very small data set, and the desired output for that data?

Comment: Don't you mean the first 5000 *rows* - You seem to be working very hard take a look at tricks like: `a = [1,2,32,3,1,-4,44]; m = min(a); i = a.index(m); print m,i;`

Comment: besides looking at builtin stuff like min(a), maybe take a look at numpy arrays, instead of lists, they are much faster (you say 'open arrays for minimum value and index', but you create lists in the line after that)

Comment: Can you add a bit of your data? (you edited with a link to those figures, but you should add a bit of data, that way we can help better)

Comment: Thank you so far. I added a self made example and the beginning of a real file. Because every file has 30000 values I'm not sure if this really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can find the minima indices much easier and faster using numpy's argmin:

```
import numpy
# setup example data
x = numpy.arange(9)
data_with_minimum = numpy.array(
    [[ 5,  3,  1,  2,  5,  8, 10, 14, 16],
     [ 8,  6,  5,  3,  1,  3,  4,  7, 10],
     [ 3,  1,  5,  8, 10, 13, 15, 18, 20]])

mi = numpy.argmin(data_with_minimum, axis = 1)
```

Then, I wanted to point you to `numpy.roll`, which could be used to shift/align the arrays, but if you are interested in plotting, it is much more elegant and logical not to modify the arrays at all (and to deal with boundary issues), but just to shift the line plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()

for i, row in enumerate(data_with_minimum):
    plt.plot(x - mi[i], row)

plt.xlabel('offset from minimum')
plt.show()
```

[image: aligned line plots]

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But here's how I would plot two lines so that their minimum values are aligned:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.random_sample(10)
b = np.random.random_sample(10)

# say we want to align "b" to "a" based on
# the minima as you describe
a_indices = np.arange(0, len(a))
b_indices = a_indices + (a.argmin() - b.argmin())

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(a_indices, a)
plt.plot(b_indices, b)
plt.show()
```

[image]